# ERROR TypeError: elementInfo.renderer.removeClass is not a function

Tags: angular, material-design

I am creating a form using angular(material design).
There is problem with `<mat-datepicker>`, it works for 1st time and 2nd time if I click the pop-up doesn't appear at all.
On console I get following error on every click on form field:

```
ERROR TypeError: elementInfo.renderer.removeClass is not a function
```

My code;

```
 <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Start Date Time" formControlName="startDateTime" [matDatepicker]="start" (focus)="start.open()"
            required>
          <!-- <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="start"></mat-datepicker-toggle>-->
          <mat-datepicker  #start></mat-datepicker>
          <mat-error *ngIf="!ProgrammeForm.StartDateTime?.CheckCurrentDate">Start Date cannot be smaller than current date</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I faced the same problem. Updating angular, and flex-layout versions to latest solved the issue. Check this answer https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18922#issuecomment-348529306 it might help

Comment: thanks for your reply... I just used yarn instead of npm and the error is rectified :)